# First posts answer with no question (review audit)

Tags: bug, questions, review-audits

Not sure if this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), but it was an obvious review audit :

[image]

Comment: Good. It means you were paying attention.

Comment: This happens when the question has been deleted and you don't have the 10,000 reputation required to see it.

Comment: FWIW - this is the audit in question: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1654437

Comment: Looks like it still served its purpose: *"Review audit failed 28 mins ago:
Hannish reviewed this 28 mins ago: No Action Needed
  "*

Comment: @WesleyMurch I'm impressed !